# Java Mail Embed URL

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-mail, scriptlet

When I'm adding an HTML URL into email body, it is not redirecting to the preferred location. This is the snippet, please tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
#location variable contains the URL
StringBuffer body = new StringBuffer("<html><body>Hi, <br/><br/>");
body.append("<p>"+cmts+"</p>");

#both the ways are not working, how to construct proper URL 
body.append("<br/><br/><a href=\"+location+\">" + location + "</a><br/>");
body.append("<br/><br/><a href="+location+">" +location + "</a><br/>");

#this is working as link only in OUTLOOK, but in other mail client it shows as plain text
body.append("<br/><br/>"+location);
```

URL:

> http://host:port/weebApp/report/viewer.html#%2Fpublic%2FSamples%2FDashboards%2_FSample_report

Comment: Can you add an example of the URL you are using?

Comment: First check this URL without javaMail either its working? It doesn't seems me to work

Comment: @Ghayel refer Last Statement in the Snippet, that way it is working. but When i'm looking in other client other than outlook, it is showing as plain text bcoz it is not enclosed in <a></a>. I want that to be in <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many ways to add href in javamail for example:

1)  `InternetHeaders headers = new InternetHeaders(); 
    headers.addHeader("Content-type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8"); 
    String aHref = "some text\n" + text + 
                   "\n<a href='http://google.com'>google.com</a>";`

2)  `String aHref = "some text\n" + text + 
                    "\n<a href='http://google.com'>google.com</a>";
                     messageBodyPart.setText(aHref,"UTF-8","html");`

UPDATE:
Make sure the content-type is set to `html` or `text/html` because `text/plain` will display it as only text

Comment: when i'm passing static url its working, but when i'm passing variable which contain URL its not working, I think i've to make this statement properly `body.append("<br/><br/><a href=\"+location+\">" + location + "</a><br/>");`

Comment: Does the variable's value already start with "http://" or not?  If it does, as in your example at the top, adding an extra "http://" isn't going to help.  After constructing the message do message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt")); and show us what you have in msg.txt.  Also, try **not** URL-encoding the URL before including it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply it was off-day here, it worked as you said, but it is redirecting to variable name instead of URL. plz check this image [Image](http://ibin.co/2X0emZxlFH4U)

Comment: @GeekExplorer why you are not passing URL without %2 or such signs? Either provide plain URL in your code like http://www.google.com or use java.net.URLEncoded.encode and java.net.URLDecoded.decode

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the quotation marks.  Try:

```
body.append("<br/><br/><a href=\""+location+"\">" + location + "</a><br/>");
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply it was off-day here, I tried as you suggested. I was getting mail Sent Successfully msg. Plz refer this [link](http://ibin.co/2X0emZxlFH4U) on click it is redirecting to variable name instead of URL

Comment: My guess is that your quotation marks for your strings are getting mixed up with the quotation marks in the HTML.  Try using single quotes in the HTML to help distinguish the two, e.g.:
        body.append("<br/><br/><a href='"+location+"'>" + location + "</a><br/>");

Comment: I tried it @pilot7, not working. Do I've to Encode the URL, bcoz when i add the URL to Email Body it is showing mail sent successfully but not delivering the mail and if i comment out the URL it is delivering the mail. Stuck here from past few weeks unable to resolve it. :(

Comment: Please post the HTML in your e-mail you received, and I will take a  look.

Comment: `<html><body>Hi, <br><br><p>sample message</p><br><br>If you want to make comments/annotations on this dashboard please click the following link !!!<br><br>
<a href="http://host:port/jasperserver-pro/dashboard/viewer.html#%2Fpublic%2FSamples%2FDashboards%2F2._Performance_Summary_Dashboard">clickhere</a>
<br><br><img src="cid:dashboard" width="50%" height="50%" /><br><br>Thank you<br>superuser</body></html>` @pilot7 plz have a look at it.

Comment: This is a different message than what you had before.  For this message, your URL in the href contains the words, 'host' and 'port' in the place where you should have your actual hostname (e.g. 'www.mysite.com').  You probably need to define those variable and/or make sure they are treated as variables when you are creating the variable, 'location'. To help keep things straight, you might temporarily put on a different line in the e-mail message, "location variable=" + location.

Comment: just for example sake i've changed the URL to "http://host:post/..." , i'm getting this url directly from browser address bar and trying to give that URL as link in E-mail. If i'm printing it as plain text i.e. ("<br><br>"+location) its working fine. but instead of showing complete URL in the mail body i want to show "click here" which can be achieved using <a>, when i place it <a> tag Email is not delivered without any logs/errors.